# Multiple paragraphs in bibliography fields via double line breaks

Tags: biblatex, paragraphs

I would like to add abstracts of certain references (which may contain multiple paragraphs) to the main body of a document. However, when I add them using `\citefield{KEY}{abstract}`, double line breaks do not get converted to new paragraphs (using a `\par` is fine, though). Is there a way to make this work?

A working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@misc{Test1,
  abstract = {
    First paragraph.

    Second paragraph.
  }
}
@misc{Test2,
  abstract = {
    First paragraph.
    \par
    Second paragraph.
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{Test 1}

\citefield{Test1}{abstract}

\section*{Test 2}

\citefield{Test2}{abstract}

\end{document}
```

with output:
[image: Screenshot of the working example.]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80281/35864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Biber normalises all spaces and space-like characters to a single space in a very early stage of processing the `.bib` file. In particular all line breaks are converted to normal spaces and several spaces are compressed to one space.

That means that a blank line does not start a new paragraph in a `.bib` file. You need to use `\par` instead. Since the space normalisation happens so early there isn't even a way to use a Biber sourcemap to work around this issue.

If you are planning to write longer `abstract`s you may want to look into the `biblatex` option `loadfiles` and §3.13.8 *External Abstracts and Annotations* of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).  `loadfiles` allows you to store the `abstract` in an external `.tex` file where you can use normal LaTeX syntax as usual. A usage example is shown in the second part of my answer to [How to embed a review in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488913/35864).

Comment: I forgot: If you think that Biber absolutely should respect blank lines you can open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues, but I'm not sure how deeply the space normalisation is built into Biber or the underlying `btparse` library and if there is any way to get rid of it at all

Comment: Thanks for the information -- I guess I'll have to replace multiple line breaks in the abstracts with `\par`s . Do you, by any chance, know of other workarounds using other backends like `bibtex`?

Comment: Also, how is using `biblatex`'s external abstracts/annotations functionality different from using an `\input` command in the bibliography file?

Comment: @aclow `loadfiles` isn't much different from `\input`, it just does `\input`s the right thing for you automatically. I don't think using BibTeX is a viable workaround since most fancy `biblatex` features are only available with Biber. As I mentioned, the usual panacea (Biber's sourcemapping) does not work here, since the space normalisation happens so early on, so I have no `biblatex`-world-based solution. Of course it should be possible to pre-process your `.bib` file with a script or another programming language and change blank lines to `\par`. ...

Comment: ... One last option from the extended LaTeX universe, if you will, would be [`bibtool`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool). It looks as though `bibtool` should be able to help here, but I can't test that right now and probably won't have time until tomorrow or the day after that (which means I may very well forget about this if I'm not prodded about it again later).