# Annotated bibliography: two bibliographies, one bib file

Tags: biblatex, spacing, citing

I'm working on an annotated bibliography project. I have one bib file and need two bibliographies: one sorted chronologically, and the other sorted alphabetically. I want both bibliographies to include all the bib entries in my bib file. Moreover, in the bib file, each entry has a NOTE field which contains a summary of the paper/book. In the chronological bibliography, the NOTE fields are printed, but I don't want to have them twice and so they are not printed in the alphabetical bibliography. I am only allowed to use biblatex (not bibtex, amsrefs, etc.) due to other restrictions on the project. (**EDIT**: it seems we *can* use other fields other than NOTE [such as ANNOTE] for writing the summaries.)

I have two problems:

1. I don't know how to manage the labels for the alphabetical bibliography. I've used `labelprefix=A` to get reference labels like `[A1]` to avoid confusion with labels like `[1]` in the first bibliography. However, this causes a funny situation. In the NOTE field of the entries in the first bibliography, we list the cited papers in the entry. We want to see something like `[2, 4]`, but now it looks like `[A2, 4]` (this is only happening to some of the references), see the image. Another solution would be to have the labels of the second bibliography be numbers, but each entry gets the same number as in the first bibliography. This way, there is one reference number for each entry and there will be no problem. I saw some examples for handling similar situations with `refsection` or `refsegment` but I couldn't make it work. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.
2. I have manually defined a `\myspace` command to make the spacing in the NOTE field look pretty in the output. In particular, I have used this command at the beginning of the NOTE field for all the entries. Also, some of the notes which are longer have been split into paragraphs and `\myspace` is put between any two paragraphs. Is there any way to do this automatically (or in a more professional way)?

MWE:

`ABCPNT.tex`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt, backend=biber, datamodel=mrnumber, style=numeric-comp, sortcites]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, pdfstartview=FitH, linkcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{ABCPNT.bib}  % File given below
\setlength\bibitemsep{0.2cm} % Space between references
\newcommand{\myspace}{\vspace*{0.3cm}\newline} % Space before/inside the NOTE field
\newbool{killnote} \AtEveryBibitem{\ifbool{killnote}{\clearfield{note}}{}} % To suppress the NOTE field in the second bibliography

\begin{document}
\nocite{*} % Include all the bib entries in bibliographies

\section{Chronological bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none] % The first bibliography, sorted by year

\section{Alphabetic bibliography}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] % Change the sorting to name-year-title, adding a prefix A to the label of all entries
\booltrue{killnote} % Do not print the NOTE field in bib entires
\printbibliography[heading=none] % The second bibliography, sorted alphabetically
\end{document}
```

`ABCPNT.bib`

```
@article {ref1,
    AUTHOR = {Chebyshev, P.},
    TITLE = {{Lettre de M. le professeur Tchebychev a M. Fuss, sur un nouveau th{e}oreme relatif aux nombres premiers contenus dans la formes $4n+1$ et $4n+3$.}},
    FJOURNAL = {Bull. de la Classe phys. math. de l'Acad. Imp. des Sciences St. Petersburg},
    VOLUME = {11},
    YEAR = {1853},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    NOTE = {\myspace Chebyshev's paper which was the starting point of the subject.},
}
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@article{ref2,
    AUTHOR = {Phragmen, P.},
    TITLE = {{Sur le logarithme integral et la fonction $f(x)$ de Riemann}},
    YEAR  = {1891},
    FJOURNAL = {\"{O}fversigt af Kongl. Vetenskaps--Akademiens F\"{o}handlingar.},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    VOLUME = {48},
    NOTE = {\myspace \blindtext \myspace This article cites~\cites{ref4, ref5}.},
}
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@article{ref3,
    AUTHOR = {Landau, E.},
    TITLE = {{U}ber einen {S}atz von {T}schebyschef},
    JOURNAL = {Math. Ann.},
    FJOURNAL = {Mathematische Annalen},
    VOLUME = {61},
    YEAR = {1906},
    NUMBER = {4},
}
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@article{ref4,
    author={Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Sur la distribution des nombres premiers}},
    year={1914},
    volume={158},
    journal={Comptes Rendus de l'Acad. Sci. Paris},
    language={French},
    note = {\myspace This article cites~\cites{ref4, ref5}.}
    }
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@article{ref5,
    author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
    year={1916},
    journal={Acta Math.},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    note = {\myspace This article cites~\cites{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
}
```

[image]

Comment: @GregMartin I voted to reject the edit because it removed the important piece of information that the `note` field is a must and can't be changed.

Comment: In theory the citations should of course all start with `A` and the fact that they don't do that hint at an issue with the current implementation of refcontexts: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/904.

Comment: Re your second point: You can definitely automate the first `\myspace` and you can probably just separate paragraphs with `\par` (you can't use the usual blank line with Biber: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497673/35864)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @moewe. Greg is my supervisor and we (along with other people) are working this project together. He told me we can also use other fields than NOTE (like ANNOTE) for the summaries. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @moewe I appreciate your reporting the bug in Github. Someone suggested using \assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=ydnt]{bibentry} there. Is there a way to do this for all bib entries, not just one? For the other question, how can I define the first `\myspace` (blank space before each summary) into the NOTE field? Automating that would be great. Using `\par` sure seems a reasonable answer for spacing between paragraphs but I'd like to know if it is possible to change space between lines in a local environment like the NOTE field. Thanks!

Comment: @moewe I appreciate your vote to reject the original edit (not knowing the offline relationship)—there are rules here after all :)

Comment: @moewe Your suggestions have been extremely helpful! We would like to add a note of acknowledgment to you in our annotated bibliography. What is your preference for how to refer to you in our acknowledgment? (My web page is on my profile—you can find my email there if you want to communicate privately.)

Comment: @GregMartin If its OK with you, I'll be moewe. If you prefer real names you can find my name at the top of the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf).

Comment: @moewe I'm happy to abide by your preference. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since fields other than `note` are acceptable I suggest you use `annotation` instead. By default that field is not printed by most standard styles, but we can quickly change that.

As discussed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/904 the situation with the citations in the bibliography is a bit tricky. Usually I recommend not to use `\cite` in the bibliography to avoid these sort of issues. An explicit refcontext assignment (see MWE below `\assignrefcontextentries`) as suggested by PLK might help here.

The initial `\myspace` can be made redundant by issuing a `\par` (wrapped in `\setunit`) before printing the field contents. Within the field contents new paragraphs should be started with `\par`, using blank lines as usual in the rest of a `.tex` document will unfortunately not work. See [Multiple paragraphs in bibliography fields via double line breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497673/35864) and [Preserve line breaks/newlines when parsing bib file with biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80281/35864).

The redefinition of the `bibliography` environment was needed to be able to control the `\parindent` with `\bibparindent`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt, backend=biber, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A]{*}

\newtoggle{showannotation}
\toggletrue{showannotation}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{showannotation}
    {\setunit{\par}%
     \printfield{annotation}}
    {}%
  \finentry}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\bibparsep}{.5\bibitemsep}

\newlength{\bibparindent}
\setlength{\bibparindent}{0pt}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\bibparindent}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {ref1,
    AUTHOR = {Chebyshev, P.},
    TITLE = {{Lettre de M. le professeur Tchebychev a M. Fuss, sur un nouveau th{e}oreme relatif aux nombres premiers contenus dans la formes $4n+1$ et $4n+3$.}},
    FJOURNAL = {Bull. de la Classe phys. math. de l'Acad. Imp. des Sciences St. Petersburg},
    VOLUME = {11},
    YEAR = {1853},
    LANGUAGE = {french},
    annotation = {Chebyshev's paper which was the starting point of the subject.},
}
@article{ref2,
    AUTHOR = {Phragmen, P.},
    TITLE = {{Sur le logarithme integral et la fonction $f(x)$ de Riemann}},
    YEAR  = {1891},
    FJOURNAL = {\"{O}fversigt af Kongl. Vetenskaps--Akademiens F\"{o}handlingar.},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    VOLUME = {48},
    annotation = {\blindtext \par This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.},
}
@article{ref3,
    AUTHOR = {Landau, E.},
    TITLE = {{U}ber einen {S}atz von {T}schebyschef},
    JOURNAL = {Math. Ann.},
    FJOURNAL = {Mathematische Annalen},
    VOLUME = {61},
    YEAR = {1906},
    NUMBER = {4},
}
@article{ref4,
    author={Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Sur la distribution des nombres premiers}},
    year={1914},
    volume={158},
    journal={Comptes Rendus de l'Acad. Sci. Paris},
    language={French},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.}
}
@article{ref5,
    author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
    year={1916},
    journal={Acta Math.},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\section{Chronological bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\section{Alphabetic bibliography}
\togglefalse{showannotation}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] 
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Two bibliographies]

Comment: What is the benefit of using `annotation` instead of `note`?

Comment: @GregMartin It is semantically the better choice: According to the `biblatex` documentation `annotation` is supposed to be used for annotated bibliographies, whereas `note` holds "[m]iscellaneous bibliographic data which does not fit into any other field". Plus, `note` is not always the last field to be printed in the bibliography, which could mean that the comment is not the last part of the bibliography entry, which would look awkward. With `annotation` we had to decide for ourselves where to put it (at the end with `finentry`) so we can be sure it is really at the end.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I'm busy today but I'll try your code on our project and let you know how it goes. Using `annotation` instead of `note` is in fact a brilliant idea; I remember I had to manually change the position of where the `page` field is printed because it was printed after the `note` field and made the PDF look awful.

Comment: @moewe just a quick comment: can we have `[2, 4]` instead of `[A4], [A2]`?

Comment: @AmirHossein Sure, replace `\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A]{*}` with `\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=ynt]{*}`.

Comment: @moewe I just tried and now I see [ref2, ref4] in bold letters. There is something strange happening here! LaTeX recognizes the references only when `labelprefix=A` is there.

Comment: @AmirHossein I just checked with the example and it worked for me. Does it work for you when you try that in the example I posted? It is important that you have one bibliography with the refcontext settings you are requesting in `\assignrefcontextentries*`. In the example there is such a bibliography for `\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=ynt]{*}`, but things will go wrong if you say for example `\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=nyt]{*}` because there is no bibliography to that refcontext (we only have `sorting=ynt` and `sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A`, but not `sorting=nyt`). ...

Comment: ... If you are still having trouble I suggest you ask a new question with an MWE showing what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: Will do! Thanks.

Comment: Posted two more questions about this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500428/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500438/