# Annotated bibliography: two bibliographies, labels are not printed correctly

Tags: biblatex, citing

As a follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499458/48840) and moewe's answer, I am trying to figure out why the citation labels in the annotated bibliography are not printed correctly. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt, backend=biber, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A]{*}

\newtoggle{showannotation}
\toggletrue{showannotation}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{showannotation}
    {\setunit{\par}%
     \printfield{annotation}}
    {}%
  \finentry}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\bibparsep}{.5\bibitemsep}

\newlength{\bibparindent}
\setlength{\bibparindent}{0pt}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\bibparindent}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {ref1,
    AUTHOR = {Chebyshev, P.},
    TITLE = {{Lettre de M. le professeur Tchebychev a M. Fuss, sur un nouveau th{e}oreme relatif aux nombres premiers contenus dans la formes $4n+1$ et $4n+3$.}},
    FJOURNAL = {Bull. de la Classe phys. math. de l'Acad. Imp. des Sciences St. Petersburg},
    VOLUME = {11},
    YEAR = {1853},
    LANGUAGE = {french},
    annotation = {Chebyshev's paper which was the starting point of the subject.},
}
@article{ref2,
    AUTHOR = {Phragmen, P.},
    TITLE = {{Sur le logarithme integral et la fonction $f(x)$ de Riemann}},
    YEAR  = {1891},
    FJOURNAL = {\"{O}fversigt af Kongl. Vetenskaps--Akademiens F\"{o}handlingar.},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    VOLUME = {48},
    annotation = {\blindtext \par This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.},
}
@article{ref3,
    AUTHOR = {Landau, E.},
    TITLE = {{U}ber einen {S}atz von {T}schebyschef},
    JOURNAL = {Math. Ann.},
    FJOURNAL = {Mathematische Annalen},
    VOLUME = {61},
    YEAR = {1906},
    NUMBER = {4},
}
@article{ref4,
    author={Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Sur la distribution des nombres premiers}},
    year={1914},
    volume={158},
    journal={Comptes Rendus de l'Acad. Sci. Paris},
    language={French},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.}
}
@article{ref5,
    author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
    year={1916},
    journal={Acta Math.},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\section{Chronological bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\section{Alphabetic bibliography}
\togglefalse{showannotation}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] 
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Now if I want to see `[4, 5]` instead of `[A4, A5]` (get rid of the A), so as moewe [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499458/annotated-bibliography-two-bibliographies-one-bib-file/499550#comment1263909_499550), the natural way to do that would be to remove `labelprefix=A` in `assignrefcontextentries`. However, when I do that, the reference labels are not printed correctly (my own labels are printed: `[ref4, ref5]`). I've attached a screenshot. I do not understand why having a label prefix would confuse biblatex from printing the cite labels.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\assignrefcontextentries[<refcontext>]{<entrykey>}` can only go to an *existing* refcontext for `<entrykey>`. A refcontext exists for an entry if the entry is printed in a bibliography in that refcontext.

Since you issue `\assignrefcontextentries*[<refcontext>]{*}`, the refcontext must be valid for all entries.

The following simplified example shows what is going on

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=ynt, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A]{*}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography[title={\texttt{sorting=ynt}}]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] 
\printbibliography[title={\texttt{sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A}}]
\end{document}
```

compiles fine and produces

[image: citations from last context with "A"s]

Similarly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=ynt, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=ynt]{*}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography[title={\texttt{sorting=ynt}}]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] 
\printbibliography[title={\texttt{sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A}}]
\end{document}
```

works and produces

[image: citations from the first refcontext without "A"]

These examples come out as desired because in both cases the refcontexts used in `\assignrefcontextentries` exists for all entries.

If we were to pick a non-existing refcontext (`sorting=nyt` without a `labelprefix`) we'd end up with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=ynt, defernumbers]{biblatex}

\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=nyt]{*}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography[title={\texttt{sorting=ynt}}]

\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] 
\printbibliography[title={\texttt{sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A}}]
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations not found]

---

For your example that means that you need

```
\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=ynt]{*}
```

instead of

```
\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A]{*}
```

Not only do you have to remove the `labelprefix`, you also need to change the sorting. The reason for that is as in the simplified examples above that the refcontext `sorting=nyt` alone does not exist.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, sorting=ynt, defernumbers]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\assignrefcontextentries*[sorting=ynt]{*}

\newtoggle{showannotation}
\toggletrue{showannotation}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \iftoggle{showannotation}
    {\setunit{\par}%
     \printfield{annotation}}
    {}%
  \finentry}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{.5\baselineskip}
\setlength{\bibparsep}{.5\bibitemsep}

\newlength{\bibparindent}
\setlength{\bibparindent}{0pt}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\bibparindent}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {ref1,
    AUTHOR = {Chebyshev, P.},
    TITLE = {{Lettre de M. le professeur Tchebychev a M. Fuss, sur un nouveau th{e}oreme relatif aux nombres premiers contenus dans la formes $4n+1$ et $4n+3$.}},
    FJOURNAL = {Bull. de la Classe phys. math. de l'Acad. Imp. des Sciences St. Petersburg},
    VOLUME = {11},
    YEAR = {1853},
    LANGUAGE = {french},
    annotation = {Chebyshev's paper which was the starting point of the subject.},
}
@article{ref2,
    AUTHOR = {Phragmen, P.},
    TITLE = {{Sur le logarithme integral et la fonction $f(x)$ de Riemann}},
    YEAR  = {1891},
    FJOURNAL = {\"{O}fversigt af Kongl. Vetenskaps--Akademiens F\"{o}handlingar.},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    VOLUME = {48},
    annotation = {\blindtext \par This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.},
}
@article{ref3,
    AUTHOR = {Landau, E.},
    TITLE = {{U}ber einen {S}atz von {T}schebyschef},
    JOURNAL = {Math. Ann.},
    FJOURNAL = {Mathematische Annalen},
    VOLUME = {61},
    YEAR = {1906},
    NUMBER = {4},
}
@article{ref4,
    author={Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Sur la distribution des nombres premiers}},
    year={1914},
    volume={158},
    journal={Comptes Rendus de l'Acad. Sci. Paris},
    language={French},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.}
}
@article{ref5,
    author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
    year={1916},
    journal={Acta Math.},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\section{Chronological bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\section{Alphabetic bibliography}
\togglefalse{showannotation}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nyt, labelprefix=A] 
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with citations to the <code>ynt</code> refcontext]

Comment: Excellent! I checked and it works, thank you.