# Having 1961/62 in the year field rather than 1961

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, sorting

This is the fourth question on the annotated bibliography project we are working on ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499458/), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500428/), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500438/)). This was originally a part of the third question but as [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) suggested, I'm making a new question for it.

I have a long annotated bibliography (200+ entries) in biblatex. In the `year` field of some of the entries, there is a sequence like `1961/62` rather than a single 4 digit number (`1961` or `1962`). Hence, when I sort the references chronologically, such entries appear first. One solution would be to remove `/62` and only include `1961` as the year. However, we want to be as loyal as possible to the main source (usually MathSciNet) so the reader is not confused when browsing for the references. So, we want `1961/62` to appear in the `year` field.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[sorting=ynt, backend=biber, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {ref1,
    AUTHOR = {Chebyshev, P.},
    TITLE = {{Lettre de M. le professeur Tchebychev a M. Fuss, sur un nouveau th{e}oreme relatif aux nombres premiers contenus dans la formes $4n+1$ et $4n+3$.}},
    FJOURNAL = {Bull. de la Classe phys. math. de l'Acad. Imp. des Sciences St. Petersburg},
    VOLUME = {11},
    YEAR = {1853},
    LANGUAGE = {french},
    annotation = {Chebyshev's paper which was the starting point of the subject.},
}
@article{ref2,
    AUTHOR = {Phragmen, P.},
    TITLE = {{Sur le logarithme integral et la fonction $f(x)$ de Riemann}},
    YEAR  = {1891},
    FJOURNAL = {\"{O}fversigt af Kongl. Vetenskaps--Akademiens F\"{o}handlingar.},
    LANGUAGE = {French},
    VOLUME = {48},
    annotation = {\blindtext \par This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.},
}
@article{ref3,
    AUTHOR = {Landau, E.},
    TITLE = {{U}ber einen {S}atz von {T}schebyschef},
    JOURNAL = {Math. Ann.},
    FJOURNAL = {Mathematische Annalen},
    VOLUME = {61},
    YEAR = {1906},
    NUMBER = {4},
}
@article{ref4,
    author={Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Sur la distribution des nombres premiers}},
    year={1961/62},
    volume={158},
    journal={Comptes Rendus de l'Acad. Sci. Paris},
    language={French},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref4, ref5}.}
}
@article{ref5,
    author={Hardy, G. H. and Littlewood, J. E. },
    title={{Contributions to the theory of the Riemann zeta-function and the theory of the distribution of primes}},
    year={1916},
    journal={Acta Math.},
    volume={41},
    number={1},
    annotation = {This article cites~\cite{ref1, ref4, ref3}.},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}



\section{Chronological bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

And here is how it looks:
[image: Year issue]
As you see, the first entry should appear last in the chronological order, but it appears first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
year   = {1961/62},
```

produces the Biber warning

> ```
> WARN - year field '1961/62' in entry 'ref4' is not an integer
>          - this will probably not sort properly.
> ```

---

Ideally, you would use ISO 8601 date input with the `date` field. Then a year range is given as `yyyy/yyyy`

```
date = {1961/1962},
```

By default this will not produce

> 1961/62

though, it will show as

> 1961–1962

There is a way to get `biblatex` to use slashes here, but it is a bit involved, see https://github.com/LukasCBossert/biblatex-archaeologie/issues/133.

---

If you insist on using `year` with a 'hard-coded' `1961/62` you can get the sorting right using `sortyear`

```
year     = {1961/62},
sortyear = {1961},
```

Comment: I think `sortyear` does the job. I checked and it works perfectly. Thank you!