# Add text after entry based on a new field for an annotated bibliography

Tags: biblatex

Adding

```
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{cstatement}
\AtEveryBibitem{[\printfield{cstatement}]}
```

to `biblatex.cfg` is *almost* what I want. For every bibtex entry with a keyword `cstatement="This is a foo"`, this code casuse biblatex to print in the bibliography entrpy with "This is a foo" just beforehand.

But what I *actually* need is for this new entry to appear just after the entry, as in an annotated bibliography. The ``addendum'' entry is also **almost** what I want but, but not quite because 1) i want to use this custom keyword and 2) i'd like more control over the formatting. Namely, I'd like the literal text in cstatement to appear like

```
\item [bibentry here]\\\ \\[cstatement literal text here]
```

where the `\\\ \\` causes there to be a blank line between the cstatement's text and the bibentry. (The newline shouldn't be there unless cstatement exists.) This should work on any bibtex entry type (article, inproceedings, etc.)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/499458/35864

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would issue a `\par` before the field. Then you can control the distance between the actual entry and the annotation with `\bibparsep`. A very simple way to add something to the end of the bibliography entry is by redefining the bibmacro `finentry` that all good bibliography styles should use.

In the example here I used the field `annotation` instead of `cstatement`, but if you declare the field in a data model file, you can simply exchange all mentions of  `annotation` for `cstatement`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibparsep}{.5\baselineskip}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \setunit{\finentrypunct\par}%
  \printfield{annotation}%
  \finentry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author     = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title      = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date       = {1980},
  annotation = {This is a foo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Annotated bibliography entry.]

Comment: Two follow-up questions:
(1) Is it possible to extend this code so that *each* annotation text will be preceded by some text specified in this four-liner?
(2) Is there a chance to extend this code so that it works for a new field name that I define on my own? (Rather than 'annotation', which seems to exist already.)
[asking here in case both is easy -- otherwise I will write a new post.]

Comment: @Prof.Chaos (1) `\DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{Text preceding annotation: #1}` (though ideally that would be done with a bibstring: `\NewBibliographyString{annintro}\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{annintro = {introduction for annotation},}\DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{\bibstring{annintro}\addcolon\space #1}`). (2) New fields can be added as explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/163303/35864.